# How to control \tkzAxeXY number formatting

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I've made this drawing:
 [image]

With this code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzClip
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, -3/2/A, 4/-4/B, 4/0/M}
    \tkzDrawLine(A,B)
    \tkzInterLL(A,B)(O,M) \tkzGetPoint{S}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,S)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](A,B)
    \tkzMarkAngle[fill= blue!40,size=2cm, opacity=.6](M,S,A);
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1](M,S,A){$\alpha$ };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

But I want to control the numbers on the axes:

- I want to have a smaller size of the numbers
- I want to control it to make it 0,2,4,6 or 0,1,3

For a bonus, is this the good way to find the intersection between AB and the x-axis?

I know this is possible with `\begin{axis} ... \end{axis}`, but I (now) prefer the `\tkzAxeXY` command.

Comment: The placement is already treated in another question in the forum. I just want a smaller size  of the numbers. ;-)

Comment: I've adjusted: you can edit, you know ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `step` and `font` options of `\tkzLabelX`, `\tkzDrawX`, `\tkzLabelY` and `\tkzDrawY` instead of using `tkzAxeXY` (Section 6.2 in the `tkz-base` [manual](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-base/doc/tkz-base-screen.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5]
    \tkzGrid
        \tkzLabelX[orig=false,label options={font=\tiny},step=2]
        \tkzLabelY[orig=false,label options={font=\tiny}]
        \tkzDrawX
        \tkzDrawY
        %\tkzAxeXY
    \tkzClip
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, -3/2/A, 4/-4/B, 4/0/M}
    \tkzDrawLine(A,B)
    \tkzInterLL(A,B)(O,M) \tkzGetPoint{S}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,S)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](A,B)
    \tkzMarkAngle[fill= blue!40,size=2cm, opacity=.6](M,S,A);
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 1](M,S,A){$\alpha$ };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]