# Increase size of coordinate system numbers \tkzGrid

Tags: tikz-node, tkz-collection, tkz-base

I am working on the following `TikZ` picture below. I wonder if there's a way to increase the size of the numbers of the coordinate system and the labels of the axes (x,y).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
     \documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
        \usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
        \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
        
        
    \tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
    %default radius will be 1pt. 
    cross/.default={1pt}}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale = 0.4, every node/.style={scale=0.7}]
    \tkzInit[xmax=12,ymax=12,xmin=-3,ymin=-3]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \coordinate (p1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (p2) at (6.6,5);
    \coordinate (p3) at (5,7) ;
    \draw  (0,0)node[cross = 6pt, thick, black, rotate = 90, label = {[black] above right :  \huge BS}](BS) {};
    \draw  (6.6,5) node[cross = 6pt, thick, red, rotate = 90, label = {[black] below :  \huge UE}](UE) {};
    \draw [shorten >=1em, -> ,shorten <=1em,  dashed, thick](BS) [out = 70, in = 175] to node[xshift=-20, yshift = 11, scale = 1.5]{\Large TPC}(p2);
    \draw [shorten >=1em, -> ,shorten <=1em,  dashed, thick](UE) [out = 250, in = 5] to node[xshift=-20, yshift = 11, scale = 1.5]{\Large Signal}(p1);
    \draw [->](p2) to node[xshift=12, yshift = 6]{\Huge $\vec{v}$}(p3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried this `\tkzSetUpLabel[font=\huge]` (section 41 of the [tkz-euclide](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) package)? The same syntax `[font=\large]` etc. you can also use in your labels `BS` + `UE` and node `p3`.

Comment: do you know where exactly I have to put it? I tried but it did not work for me

Comment: `\tkzAxeXY[font=\large]` seems to work. see also [How to control \tkzAxeXY number formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284103)